# display fetched data from bearer token api in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, display

im trying to display the fetched data from a bearer token API but I couldn't

I could see the data in the console

here is my code:

```
  const [products, setProdcts] = useState([]);      
fetch("https://RANDOMAPI.com/api/products", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "default",
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      console.log("response");
    
    
    {products?.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="container">
              {products.map((product) => (
                <div className="product">
                  <p>{product. Name}</p>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="empty">
              <h2>No products found</h2>
            </div>
          )}
```

Im not sure if there is any other way to display the data other than mapping

please tell me if im doing something wrong?

Comment: Where do you ever do anything with the data you receive?  All this code does is log it to the console.  Did you just forget to update the `products` state value?

Comment: where do you assign values to `products`

Comment: @David sorry i couldn't understand u correctly, how am i supposed to update products?
if u mean that i forgot to use useState no i have used it but i havent put it in the code

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka i have updated my question would u please relook at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is only being logged to the console because this is what you're doing with the data:

```
.then((json) => console.log(json))
```

Calling `console.log` logs the data to the console.  It *does not* have any effect on the `products` state value.

If you're looking to update that state value with the fetched data, update the state value:

```
.then((json) => setProdcts(json))
```

This will trigger a re-render of the component with the newly updated state data.

Comment: i got this error in the console Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function
    at App (App.js:62:1)

Comment: @HazalKaya: Then `products` is not an array.  So what is it?  Why are you expecting it to be an array?  We don't know the data you're using, you have to debug to observe it.

Comment: "products": [
        {

Comment: this is how the data starts

Comment: @HazalKaya: The information you're providing isn't entirely clear, but it *sounds like* `products` in this case is an *object* with a *property* called `products`, which is an array.  So perhaps instead what you want is: `setProdcts(json.products)`  **Always** debug to observe the actual data you're using and keep track of your data structures and types.